# Thumbnail URL to product image Magento in Flowplayer

Tags: image, magento, preview, flowplayer

I have instead Productimage a Flowplayer which shows Productmovies.

In this extension there is also a small thumbnailpreview:
http://demo.icebergcommerce.com/htc-touch-diamond.html?vgds=3
TAB "VIDEOS"

Now I want to set Thumbnail-preview instead of  Videoframe-preview in Flowplayer.

I could solve to show a Picture, but not the thumbnail.

In the following the code:

```
            ...flashvars='config={"playlist":["URL THUMBNAIL HERE",{"scaling":"fit", {$autoplayConfig} "url":"{$this->getUrl($this->video_value)}"}],"canvas":{"backgroundColor":"#000000","backgroundGradient":"none"}}' />...
```

I also find in another file, where thumbnail is posted, source-code this:

```
<div class="more-views">
        <h2><?php echo $this->__('Videos') ?></h2>
        <?php if (count($this->getVideoGallery()) > 0): ?>
        <ul class="video-gallery-links">
        <?php foreach ($this->getVideoGallery() as $_video): ?>
            <li>
                <a class="video-thumb" href="<?php echo $this->getVideoGalleryUrl( $_video ); ?>" style="width:78px; height:56px" target="_blank" onclick="<?php echo $this->getJsObjectName(); ?>.setVideo('<?php echo $_video['value_id']; ?>'); return false;" title="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_video['label']) ?>">
                    <span></span>
                    <img style="margin-top:-11px" src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($this->getProduct(), 'thumbnail', $_video['file'])->resize(78,78); ?>" width="78" height="78" alt="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_video['label']) ?>" />
                </a>
            </li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        </ul>
        <?php endif;?>
    </div>
```

So which code i have to implement that for every video instead videoframe the specific product-thumbnail-image will be shown?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(300); ?>" width="300" height="300" alt="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>" />
```

You can change the size to what you want, but this is just the thumbnail from the product list.phtml page.

Comment: Thank you very much, but this did not work. now i see just black screen: `code` <param name="flashvars" value='config={"playlist":["<img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(300); ?>" width="300" height="300" alt="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>" />",{"scaling":"fit", {$autoplayConfig} "url":"{$this->getUrl($this->video_value)}"}],"canvas":{"backgroundColor":"#000000","backgroundGradient":"none"}}' />
`code`